# RabbitMQ: Change the default port of the server

Tags: rabbitmq

Hi I'm fairly new to the rabbitMQ and i'm using c# on Windows and i need to change the port to communicate with the server. I've searched a lot in the rabbitMQ documentation but it can be very confused. Can someone teach me the steps to change the port? Initially i've tried changing the port in the connection configurations of the client program like this:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
//connection hostname etc...
factory.Port =8080;
```

But i supose that's not enough right? Can someone teach me how to do it??

Comment: Do you need to change in the client side or in the server side?

Comment: I think I need both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to communicate with the server on a different port you need to first tell RabbitMQ what port it should listen on.

The easiest way is to customize it through environment variables:

> If you need to customise names, ports, locations, it is easiest to
>   configure environment variables in the Windows dialogue: Start >
>   Settings > Control Panel > System > Advanced > Environment Variables.
>
> Create or edit the system variable name and value. For environment
>   changes to take effect on Windows, the service must be re-installed.
>   It is not sufficient to restart the service.

for more info check official docs: http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html#customise-general-unix-environment

Comment: In this case do i alter the RABBITMQ_NODE_PORT right? because i tried that and it dint work! :S